# AMRQ (Another mod_rewrite rule quest)

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Here the context:
I want, without having to modify URLs inside my php code, to get in address bar

`http://website.tdn/somepath/news-246-Some-title.html`

instead of:

`http://website.tdn/somepath/lireNews.php?idnews=246&titre=Some-title`

(means I want to have both URLs working but the lireNews.php?blah would have to redirrect to news-###-title.html)
here my htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^lireNews.php?idnews=([0-9]+)\&titre=(.*)\$ news-$1-$2.html [NC,R,L]
```

Actually, this code is not working at all, news-246-Some-title.html gives me a 404 error and lireNews.php?idnews=246&titre=Some-title giving me the webpage without redirection.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Is your htaccess in root folder or somewhere else ?

Comment: @JustinIurman : Right now, it is located in a folder (_subdomain.domain.tdn/somepath/_) but i plan to move the whole website in the subdomain's root folder when the developpers will finish the website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking your comment into consideration, you can put this code in your htaccess (in `somepath` folder)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /somepath/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /lireNews\.php\?idnews=([0-9]+)&titre=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule . news-%1-%2.html? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^news-([0-9]+)-(.+)\.html$ lireNews.php?idnews=$1&titre=$2 [L]
```

If you move it to root subdomain folder, all you have to do is replace `RewriteBase /somepath/` by `RewriteBase /`

Comment: mmhhh, weirdly this still not redirect to rewrited URL


content of my .htaccess

`RewriteEngine on`
`RewriteBase /V3.6/`

`RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /lireNews\.php?idnews=([0-9]+)&titre=([^\s]+)`
`RewriteRule . news-%1-%2.html [R=301,L]`

`RewriteRule ^news-([0-9]+)-(.+)\.html$ lireNews.php?idnews=$1&titre=$2 [L]`

`RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /ficheprojet\.php?idProjet=([0-9]+)&titre=([^\s]+)`
`RewriteRule . projet-%1-%2.html [R=301,L]`

`RewriteRule ^projet-([0-9]+)-(.+)\.html$ ficheprojet.php?idProjet=$1&titre=$2 [L]`

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to escape the `?` in `RewriteCond`. I edited my answer, and i tested it. This worked, should be the same for you

Comment: Thanks, working like a charm. Does not update the URL when handled by ajax script but it's another story. =]